# Spring "session" scope of a bean

Tags: java, spring, scope

It seems to me that "session" scope is another means to keep objects in session as

using setAttrubute / getAttribute

Correct?

You know, dont know why, it does not work for me.

<bean id="sabreUser" class="util.MyUser" factory-method="getSomeUser" scope="session">

<const args...>

What I see is that after the initialization and initial deploy the MyUser properties are correct.

Then, in the first session I change MyUser property, the session is closed.

The second session runs and it sees the last set value from the previous session!

What does that mean?

I expect this object to be initialized whenever a new session starts. But it better looks as singleton, though you see - "session" attribute is set.

I can see the cause of the problem in that a Servlet's fields is initialized with @Autowired
so, once it is initialized, every other session will see its fields set and does not "ReWire" this properties. It happens once? How to overcome this problem?

Comment: where are these methods setProperty / getProperty ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Spring session does not exactly match the HttpSession, and even the Spring documentation on the @SessionAttributes annotation says that it might be stored in the session or "some conversational storage". I got that from [The Spring docs for 2.5](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/mvc.html)
I've basically quit trying to make sense of it, and just got on with my life, if I want something stored in the HttpSession, I just have Spring inject the HttpSession to me, assuming you're using Spring MVC its pretty easy, instructions on the same page.

Answer (score 1):

Session-scoped beans are beans that live throughout the http session. They are stored in the session via `setAttribute` in some way.

So - yes.

Answer (score 1):

Session scoped beans are stored in Http Session by Spring framework. This scope is valid  only in the context of Web application.It also works for Portlet envionments . When using in Portlet environment, there are two notions of session, application scope and portlet scope (default).