# Thymeleaf and sessions

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

1) Who know please provide more information about session in pages with Thymeleaf template engine.

2) Session by default is enabled in Thymeleaf like in JSP?

3) In Thymeleaf there any limitations with session objects?

4) In Thymeleaf have(or need) some specific constructions for working with sessions?

In JSP we have by default session="true" and we must use something like this:

```
<jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8" session="false" />
```

Google or Thymeleaf forum have no enough information about how is work this template engine with sessions.

my English on basic level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thymeleaf is a template engine or optionally (although most often) used as a view layer in Spring MVC. As a template engine, it doesn't have anything to do with session. Its job is just to process EL and spit out markup.

Spring MVC on the other hand, will allow session bean scope, and can give you access to and modification of the session. See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html

Also see:
[Spring MVC: HTTP session management "equivalent"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8680529/spring-mvc-http-session-management-equivalent)
[Spring "session" scope of a bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788774/spring-session-scope-of-a-bean)

Answer (score 4):

use #httpSession or ${session} Object with its method to check the ServletSession . Please make sure that you are doing all the operation using ExpressionLanguage.

[Click Here](http://www.javabeat.net/context-objects-thymeleaf/) To know more.

Answer (score 0):

You can use session easily with thymelaaf .

```
   session.setAttribute("mySessionAttribute", "someValue");
```

You can access direct session attribute .

```
${#session.getAttribute('mySessionAttribute')}
```